# Creating NPM global module w/ Babel transpile

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I created a project to be used on the command line. Works just as expected running with

```
node index.js
```

However, when I set up the project up to be able to be installed globally using npm, I am getting this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import fs from 'fs';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Which means that when my app is getting installed globally, Babel isn't doing its job.

The "bin" field in package.json references this file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
require('./index');
```

And the required index file is just this:

```
require('babel-core/register');
require('./app/main');
```

The first line of that ./app/main.js file is where the error comes from:

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

How can I make global installs use Babel so that I can still write code that uses newer Javascript syntax/features? Local install, the app works as expected.

Comment: Is babel-core/register a dependency for your global install?

Comment: I have the same issue :( Trying to create a nice way to import modules locally I'm using `npm i -s ..\module-name` but the transpiling in the imported module doesn't work :(